# Rescale prediction to correct dispersion due to correlation between response and residuals in Random Forrest Regression

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, random-forest

I am using Random Forest Regression and I observe a strong positive correlation between the residuals ($\hat{u}$) and the response variable ($y$) which lead to a dispersion : predictions are underestimated, resp. over estimated, for large, resp. small, values of response variable. Note that there is no correlation between predictions - estimated response variable - ($\hat{y}$) and residuals ($\hat{u}$) which is expected for Random Forest.

This issue is due to the fact that Random Forest can be seen as a local average smoother (page 3 in this [article](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7562-when-do-random-forests-fail.pdf)) and is well documented as in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28732/response-distribution-dependent-bias-in-random-forest-regression) or in [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180546/random-forest-regression-residuals-correlated-with-response).

An answer, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30635/148110), suggests that one way to correct for this dispersion is to "wrap the model in some kind of classical regression which would rescale the response to its desired distribution."

Is it possible to compute some predictions $y_c = f(\hat{y})$ that are corrected for this dispersion ? And how ?